I try to ,make a fixture in Django, using dumpdata, and instead of letters i have symbols
when i try do to a fixture in Django, i use dumpdata, and when I create a JSON file, where the name is, instead of letters there are some symbols, I use this command
python manage.py dumpdata goods.Categories > fixtures\goods\cats.json
my json file after, is looking like this
{
"model": "goods.categories",
"pk": 4,
"fields": {
"name": "┬ёх ЄютрЁ√",
"slug": "all"
}

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
